# How to update a windows form app (via LAN) using c#?

Tags: c#

I have a simple windows form application which I want to enable auto update feature (without using any third party app), so I add this code to the **Form Load** event of the app (the form has a label called label1 and its text is in the form **v1.1**)

```
XDocument doc=XDocument.Load(@"\\PC-10\TEST Update\share\checkver.xml");
double chkver=Convert.ToDouble(doc.Descendants("version").First().Value);
double currver=Convert.ToDouble(label1.Text.Substring(1,3));
if (chkver>currver) {
    string exePath = Application.ExecutablePath;
    string x=exePath.Substring(0,exePath.Length-10)+"\\updater.exe";
    Process.Start(x);
    this.Close();
    }
```

The **checkver.xml** is a xml file located on the same folder as the updated **myapp.exe** and the **updater.exe** is located on the folder where the actual running app **myapp.exe** is i.e. *Program Files*

**checkver.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<myapp>
    <version>1.2</version>
</myapp>
```

**updater.exe**:

```
Console.WriteLine("Updating the app...please wait!");
string exePath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
string x=exePath.Substring(0,exePath.Length-12);
File.Copy(@"\\PC-10\TEST Update\share\myapp.exe", x+"\\myapp.exe",true);
Console.WriteLine("Update completed!");
Process.Start(x+"\\myapp.exe");
```

When I run this from the actual projects bin folder it runs fine but when I create a setup file and install it on *Program Files* I get an error

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path ...
```

and a message **updater has stopped working**.
Why is this happening?

Also is there a way to make this process faster(specially the update checking part)?

Comment: Your application should run with administrator privileges.

Comment: @FaizanRabbani how and where do I add that? can you please show me..

Comment: Which program will invoke `updater.exe`?

Comment: The `myapp.exe` in the *Program Files* folder

Comment: Instead of directly starting the process, try adding these lines:

`ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(x);
   info.UseShellExecute = true;
   info.Verb = "runas";
   Process.Start(info);`

Comment: In order for above lines to work properly, `myapp.exe` should be running with administrative privileges itself.

Comment: @FaizanRabbani how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing I would do is check if `myapp.exe` is running with elevated privileges or not:

```
private static bool IsAdministrator()
{
    var identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
    var principal = new WindowsPrincipal(identity);
    return principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
}
```

Run `updater.exe`.

```
if(IsAdministrator())
{
    //.......
    if (chkver>currver) 
    {
        string exePath = Application.ExecutablePath;
        string x=exePath.Substring(0,exePath.Length-10)+"\\updater.exe";
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(x); 
        info.UseShellExecute = true; 
        info.Verb = "runas"; 
        Process.Start(info);
        Environment.Exit(1); //Use .Exit(1) instead of this.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply added a app.manifest file to my project like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <!-- UAC Manifest Options
             If you want to change the Windows User Account Control level replace the 
             requestedExecutionLevel node with one of the following.

        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />

            Specifying requestedExecutionLevel element will disable file and registry virtualization. 
            Remove this element if your application requires this virtualization for backwards
            compatibility.
        -->
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>

  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
    <application>
      <!-- A list of the Windows versions that this application has been tested on and is
           is designed to work with. Uncomment the appropriate elements and Windows will 
           automatically selected the most compatible environment. -->

      <!-- Windows Vista -->
      <!--<supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}" />-->

      <!-- Windows 7 -->
      <!--<supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}" />-->

      <!-- Windows 8 -->
      <!--<supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}" />-->

      <!-- Windows 8.1 -->
      <!--<supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}" />-->

      <!-- Windows 10 -->
      <!--<supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}" />-->

    </application>
  </compatibility>

  <!-- Indicates that the application is DPI-aware and will not be automatically scaled by Windows at higher
       DPIs. Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) applications are automatically DPI-aware and do not need 
       to opt in. Windows Forms applications targeting .NET Framework 4.6 that opt into this setting, should 
       also set the 'EnableWindowsFormsHighDpiAutoResizing' setting to 'true' in their app.config. -->
  <!--
  <application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <windowsSettings>
      <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>
    </windowsSettings>
  </application>
  -->

  <!-- Enable themes for Windows common controls and dialogs (Windows XP and later) -->
  <!--
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity
          type="win32"
          name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
          version="6.0.0.0"
          processorArchitecture="*"
          publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
          language="*"
        />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  -->

</assembly>
```

It seems to solve the issue I had...but not 100% sure whether it is the right solution....